# Replacing a " - " with a single space? Replace method not working

Tags: c#, string, replace

i was working on a personal program, and in it, i get some strings which may have a space hyphen space. or something like this: **" - "** and what I have to do is replace this with a single space. Now, the problem is, when i try to use a replace method from the c# library it doesn't seem to do anything. 
This is what i tried:

```
string firsttext = firsttextbox.Text.ToLower();
string name = firsttext.Replace(" - ", " ");
```

But this fails to replace the string in firsttext's space hyphen space pattern with a single space. So when i try to use this text for example:

```
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion
```

it just returns this into string name:

```
Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion
```

however it should actually be returning this:

```
Code Geass Lelouch of the Rebellion
```

Whats wrong with my idea? Or can I do it differently? Thanks for the help in advance.

Full code for those requested: 
http://pastebin.com/hwUtFe8N

Comment: Is it a `-` or a `–`? (Look closely...)

Comment: Since you are calling ToLower on the input, and yet what is being returned is properly cased, my guess is that you are later not using the name variable, but the original firsttextbox.Text. Myabe if you give us more code We can find the problem?

Comment: it is the former, a single simple hyphen `-`

Comment: Assuming you copied and pasted the text and code here, everything looks correct - even the `-`, and your code works for me when tested.  Are you sure you're running against the latest source?  (Try a project rebuild, etc.)

Comment: I am using the name variable later on only, but yes i just updated the post.

Comment: Well, [`String.Replace` isn't broken](http://ideone.com/eUfRW). Post a code sample that illustrates the problem etc.

Comment: A really silly question: are you printing the `name` or the `firsttext`?

Comment: Look at the ASCII codes for each character and make sure they're the same as the standard space and hyphen.  If the text is coming from a database or other source it may have different character codes.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob, are you sure you posted the relevant code on Pastebin? You're never replacing `" - "` with `" "`...

Comment: Make sure your spaces aren't actually a different [Unicode space](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html) too.  I would open up the debugger on that line and play in the immediate window to see what was going on.  `String.Replace` isn't the issue.

Comment: There's is nothing wrong in the code you mentioned here, it gives the correct output for "Code Geass - Lelouch of the Rebellion" as an input. Debug n put a watch to see details n let us know.

Comment: ok, guys, let me try what DotNetUser Just suggested, and then get back on that

Comment: Hmm, got it working thanks for all the help, and why was this down-voted, just wondering? Turns out it was the way i structured it out, just need a slight adjustment of the flow control.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob Presumably because you posted a snippet of code that works just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code, I only see `.Replace(" ", "-");`
*(eg. Replace `space` with `dash`)*

I don't see what you describe, which is replacing a `space-dash-space` with just a `space`.

**In otherwords, your code doesn't match your question.**